# styling A word press content manually with code

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, styles

im trying to style my WP post which is located in Single.php file ,
for the record this file contains

">

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div  <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
     <div class="card-header">
            <h2><a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
     </div>
     <div class="card-body">
           <div class="entry">
                  <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

and i dont know how to style it cus there are no classes for anything in the said posts .
any ideas how to style my content with code and manually ???

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it with following code.

first you will have to declare a class 

<div  <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class("my-custom-css"); ?>>

now you define css in your theme css file

.my-custom-css{
//do css stuff here
}
```

Comment: So here is the thing lets say i have a post that i want to change the col's on that like

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a class name and then create a custom css for the just created style

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).